# Command for determining my public IP?

Tags: networking

If I check with [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20IP%20address), I can see my public IP. Is there something on the Ubuntu command-line which will yield me the same answer?

Comment: "having dynamic IP", "SSH using some other system across the internet", "the command which will display the present PUBLIC IP". You see the chicken/egg problem here? How would you be able to run commands on a remote server without knowing its address? You might be more interested in services like no-ip.com / DynDNS.org.

Comment: one cannot SSH without knowing the public IP my friend... dynDNS costs a lot and no-ip tough works but the situation don't allow that... anyway the question has been already answered.. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: PS https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ip (no command line, but no big brother G neither)

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question, but I would like to see an alert when my public IP address changes. For now, I'm just using the following answers in a crontab with `notify-send`.

Comment: great solutions below. For Centos use: `ifconfig eth1 | sed -nre '/^[^ ]+/{N;s/^([^ ]+).*inet *([^ ]+).*/\2/p}'` where eth1 is the network device o interest, you can omit the 'et1' string to show all ips of all adapters. Instead of `\2` you can write `\1 \2` to show the names of each adapter too.

Comment: None of the answers shows the correct approach. Since I don't have enough reputation to post an answer I will post a comment on how to get it without relying on external services. Just run on terminal `$ hostname --ip-address`

Answer (score 1148, accepted):

If you are not behind a router, you can find it out using `ifconfig`.

If you are behind a router, then your computer will not know about the public IP address as the router does a network address translation.  You could ask some website what your public IP address is using `curl` or `wget` and extract the information you need from it:

```
curl -s https://checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

or shorter

```
curl https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

Comment: ty - right after I posted, I realized that I didn't google for an answer first: looks like this will work `curl -s checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'`  Other possibilities are listed here:  http://www.go2linux.org/what-is-my-public-ip-address-with-linux

Comment: If he agrees I could also put this into my answer. However,I am usually against solving the problem for someone, instead I regard also "pointers into a direction" as answer. Users wont understand the context of what they are doing if they are always faced with complete solutions.

Comment: sure - you can add it to your answer

Comment: To clarify: That was a hack, and a very ugly one at that, so I did an edit to make it simpler and something that people can remember.

Comment: Exacly as Giovanni P stated. The OP should change the accepted anwser.

Comment: This worked for me; a quick, correct result. Maybe something changed/changed back.

Comment: curl -s http://ipinfo.io/ip

Comment: Be careful to use proper quoting of variable names if you use the results of these sorts of external services for variables in a script. If one of these services gets hacked it is possible someone could inject dangerous code into your command line.

Comment: The shortest I found was `curl ipinfo.io`.

Comment: I made an alias: `myip() { curl -s http://ipinfo.io/ip }`

Comment: I tried both solution and I have different results the first one is correct, the second one it the one from my ISP.

Comment: can you please explain the regular expression `'s/<.*$//' ` and why do you use twice `-e`?

Comment: `curl` is not installed but `wget` works perfectly.

Comment: Looks like ipinfo is requiring a key now. This no longer works quite the same.

Comment: It doesn't work for IPv6.

Comment: As of August 2019, on Ubuntu Server 18.04, the "curl https://ipinfo.io/ip" command works great. 

Question -- is there a way to add this to the motd?

Comment: I want to add this as a note for myself for the next time I google for this answer: you **must** use curl and not the browser when you have enabled the "Proxy IP Header spoofing" in the Trace chrome/firefox addon. When you enable that setting in the privacy addon, most sites mentioned in answers here fail to show you the real ip, **including** ipinfo.io! The following ones always returns correct IP address, regardless of the fake proxy headers: https://icanhazip.com, https://ident.me, https://whatismyip.network

Comment: Brilliant answer

Comment: curl https://ipinfo.io/ip still works fine in Ubuntu 22.04 as of July 2023.

Answer (score 426):

For finding the external ip, you can either use external web-based services, or use system based methods. The easier one is to use the external service, also the `ifconfig` based solutions will work in your system only if you're not behind a `NAT`. the two methods has been discussed below in detail.

## Finding external IP using external services

The easiest way is to use an external service via a commandline browser or download tool. Since `wget` is available by default in Ubuntu, we can use that.
To find your ip, use-

```
$ wget -qO- https://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
```

**Courtesy**:

- https://hawknotes.blogspot.in/2010/06/finding-your-external-ip-address.html
- https://ipecho.net/plain

You could also use `lynx`(browser) or `curl` in place of `wget` with minor variations to the above command, to find your external ip.

Using `curl` to find the ip:

```
$ curl https://ipecho.net/plain
```

For a better formatted output use:

```
$ curl https://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
```

### A faster (arguably the fastest) method using `dig` with `OpenDNS` as resolver:

> The other answers here all go over HTTP to a remote server. Some of
>   them require parsing of the output, or rely on the User-Agent header
>   to make the server respond in plain text. They also change quite
>   frequently (go down, change their name, put up ads, might change
>   output format etc.).
>
> 1. The DNS response protocol is standardised (the format will stay compatible).
> 2. Historically DNS services (OpenDNS, Google Public DNS, ..) tend to survive much longer and are more stable, scalable and generally looked
>      after than whatever new hip whatismyip.com HTTP service is hot today.
> 3. (for those geeks that care about micro-optimisation), this method should be inherently faster (be it only by a few micro seconds).
>
> Using dig with OpenDNS as resolver:

```
$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com

111.222.333.444
```

**Copied from:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81699/14497

## Finding external IP without relying on external services

- **If you know your network interface name**

Type the following in your terminal:

```
$ LANG=c ifconfig <interface_name> | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

In the above, replace `<interface_name>` with the name of your actual interface, e.g: `eth0`, `eth1`, `pp0`, etc...

**Example Usage:**

```
$ LANG=c ifconfig ppp0 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
111.222.333.444
```

- **If you don't know your network interface name**

Type the following in your terminal (this gets the name and ip address of every network interface in your system):

```
$ LANG=c ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet addr" |awk '{ if ( $1 == "inet" ) { print $2 } else if ( $2 == "Link" ) { printf "%s:" ,$1 } }' |awk -F: '{ print $1 ": " $3 }'
```

**Example Usage:**

```
$ LANG=c ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet addr" |awk '{ if ( $1 == "inet" ) { print $2 } else if ( $2 == "Link" ) { printf "%s:" ,$1 } }' |awk -F: '{ print $1 ": " $3 }'
lo: 127.0.0.1
ppp0: 111.222.333.444
```

**N.B:** Outputs are indicative and not real.

**Courtesy:** https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-get-ip-address/

**UPDATE**

1. `LANG=c` has been added to `ifconfig` based usages, so that it always gives the english output, irrespective of locale setting.

Comment: @Z9iT, Sure.. It should work in any linux distribution provided that you have wget installed. As said if you have either curl or lynx already available please use that instead. You would need root permission to install so use `sudo apt-get install wget`

Comment: The commands with ifconfig do only work, if you are not behind a NAT.

Comment: just use `-w` curl option instead of echo :) `curl -w '\n' ident.me`

Comment: This proposal using dig is pretty nice http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-bash

Comment: @binaryanomaly, thanks for that. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @saji `ifconfig` if obsolete, please use `iproute2` ;^). The command would be `ip -o -4 a s eth0 | awk '{sub(/\/.*/, "", $4);print $4}'`.

Comment: @woahguy, Please add more information, as to what didn't work for you.

Comment: I added `LANG=c ` to `ifconfig` so it always gets the english output.

Comment: The last version without external services only works, if your computer is connected **directly** to the internet which is rarely the case, otherwise you only get your local IP address.

Comment: If you'd like to retrieve your IP address into a notification you could use:
 `notify-send $(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)` which is something I use as a bound application in kubuntu

Comment: Custom `getip` command is super-fast using Google resolvers: `alias getip="echo My WAN/Public IP: $(dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | sed 's/\"//g')"`.  `time (getip)` finishes in under 0.00s

Comment: On recent `ubuntu`/`debian` one has to `grep` for `inet` and not `inet addr` to get the (local) ip.

Comment: Can't answer, but the best solution , that even handles multiple internal gateway hops is:
 -  traceroute to 8.8.8.8 for example, extract the first non-local network you find. That will be your public gateway on the ISP network.
- ping with -R to get the sources and also find the first non-public network. That's your public IP.
Have a script that does everything but can't answer.

Answer (score 154):

My favorite has always been :

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

simple, easy to type.

You will have to install curl first ;)

If ifconfig.me is down try icanhazip.com and or ipecho.net

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

or

```
curl ipecho.net
```

Comment: will this display the results inside terminal?

Comment: @Z9iT, I just checked this now. Yes, it would output the external ip in your terminal.

Comment: The response time from `ifconfig.me` seems quite a bit slower than `ipecho.net`.

Comment: If you don't have `curl` but have `wget`: `wget -U curl -qO- ifconfig.me`

Comment: [you might not need `curl`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip#comment709428_145169)

Comment: ifconfig.me does not seem to be responding :(

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi - working here. You can try one of the alternates , icanhazip.com

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ipconfig.me seams to be down. Please update your response with some other  url that works.

Comment: @valentt ifconfig.me is up here, if it is not working for you try ipecho.net and icanhazip.com

Comment: `curl ifconfig.me` does not work

Comment: @prayagupd - This answer is 5 years old and ifconfig.me goes up and down. Use another site icanhazip.com for example, second example still works.

Comment: Thanks @bodhi.zazen `curl icanhazip.com` or `curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com` (on aws at least) was working.

Comment: ifconfig.me and ipecho.net don't work anymore

Comment: @AlbertoM It worked for me :)

Comment: It's probably best to stick to services that are actually meant (and documented) to be used like that. For example, I cannot find any docs on checkip.amazonaws.com so it's not clear who runs the service or what it will do in the future. icanhazip.com is probably a good choice, it is run by Cloudflare now: https://major.io/2021/06/06/a-new-future-for-icanhazip/

Answer (score 71):

[icanhazip.com](http://icanhazip.com) is my favorite.

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

You can request IPv4 explicitly:

```
curl ipv4.icanhazip.com
```

If you don't have `curl` you can use `wget` instead:

```
wget -qO- icanhazip.com
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had to try many suggested above until I found some that is IPv6-capable.  It's a shame that such services are usually still IPv4-only.

Comment: This seems to be a good choice, it is run by CloudFlare now: https://major.io/2021/06/06/a-new-future-for-icanhazip/

Answer (score 58):

Running my own service, designed to be simple and stupid, ident.me.

Its API and implementation are documented at https://api.ident.me/

Examples from the terminal (add `https://` for security at the expense of speed):

```
curl ident.me
curl v4.ident.me
curl v6.ident.me
```

Comment: Woah, that was *really* fast!

Comment: I find [the icanhazip.com solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/145169/25773) faster and it includes a newline in the output.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed faster lately. Just tweaked my solution.

Comment: Kudos! 2 years and you are still maintaining it. Well done. "IDENTify ME", is what comes to my mind, when I need ip check :)

Comment: aws is faster `time curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com` -> `0.91s` vs `.241s` for `ident.me` Let's just pray aws doesnt go down ;)

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan - you DO realize that 0.91s is *greater* than 0.241, right? Which would make AWS *slower*. https://bit.ly/2nLGSKb

Comment: @Robear I meant `.091` . No need to be facetious with your Khan link

Comment: +1 something that works with for IPv6.

Comment: @PierreCarrier you are my spiritual animal! :) Thanks!

Comment: Added DNS and SSH support, would love to cover more grounds if anybody has suggestions. @AvindraGoolcharan please don't pray, build redundancy :)

Answer (score 53):

You could use a DNS request instead of HTTP request to find out your public IP:

```
$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

It uses `resolver1.opendns.com` dns server to resolve the magical `myip.opendns.com` hostname to *your* ip address.

Comment: This is _really_ fast. I did one warmup execution, then 10 executions each of this and `curl icanhazip.com`. Average for the `curl` version: 174ms. Average for the DNS-only version: 9ms. ~19x faster. See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81699/8383

Comment: @AdamMonsen Thank you for the link. The point of using DNS (as the answer that you've linked says) is that the response is standard (and unlikely to change) and the service (OpenDNS) might stick around longer than most of its http alternatives. The time it takes to make the request might be shadowed by the command start up time.

Comment: Yep. I wouldn't be surprised if `curl` itself is slower than `dig`. Even if they were rewritten to be as similar as possible, `curl` would still be slower; it uses HTTP (_including_ DNS) and `dig` only uses DNS.

Answer (score 39):

**Amazon AWS**

```
curl https://checkip.amazonaws.com
```

Sample output:

```
123.123.123.123
```

Also works on browser: http://checkip.amazonaws.com

I like it because:

- it returns just the plaintext IP in the reply body, nothing else
- it is from a well known provider which is unlikely to go offline anytime soon

Comment: Was looking for solution with some known name, thank you

Answer (score 19):

The one i'm using is :

```
wget -O - -q icanhazip.com
```

Yes, you can have ip :-)

Comment: I prefer `curl icanhazip.com` sometimes `wget` is the only one available, but sometimes no `wget` is available as well and `curl` is your only option (like OS/X). Either way `curl icanhazip.com` is almost as easy as `curl ifconfig.me` but much funnier ;-)

Answer (score 14):

For this, [STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389) was invented. As a client you can send a request to a publicly available STUN server and have it give back the IP address it sees. Sort of the low level whatismyip.com as it uses no HTTP and no smartly crafted DNS servers but the blazingly fast STUN protocol.

#### Using `stunclient`

If you have `stunclient` installed (`apt-get install stuntman-client` on debian/ubuntu) you can simply do:

```
$stunclient stun.services.mozilla.com
Binding test: success
Local address: A.B.C.D:42541
Mapped address: W.X.Y.Z:42541
```

where `A.B.C.D` is the IP address of your machine on the local net and `W.X.Y.Z` is the IP address servers like websites see from the outside (and the one you are looking for). Using `sed` you can reduce the output above to only an IP address:

```
stunclient stun.services.mozilla.com |
    sed -n -e "s/^Mapped address: \(.*\):.*$/\1/p"
```

However, your question was how to find it using the command line, which might exclude using a STUN client. So I wonder...

#### Using `bash`

A STUN request can be handcrafted, sent to an external STUN server using `netcat` and be post-processed using `dd`, `hexdump` and `sed` like so:

```
$echo -en '\x00\x01\x00\x08\xc0\x0c\xee\x42\x7c\x20\x25\xa3\x3f\x0f\xa1\x7f\xfd\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00' |
    nc -u -w 2 stun.services.mozilla.com 3478 |
    dd bs=1 count=4 skip=28 2>/dev/null |
    hexdump -e '1/1 "%u."' |
    sed 's/\.$/\n/'
```

The echo defines a binary STUN request (0x0001 indicates Binding Request) having length 8 (0x0008) with cookie 0xc00cee and some pasted stuff from wireshark. Only the four bytes representing the external IP are taken from the answer, cleaned and printed.

Working, but not recommended for production use :-)

P.S. Many STUN servers are available as it is a core technology for SIP and WebRTC. Using one from Mozilla should be safe privacy-wise but you could also use another: [STUN server list](http://olegh.ftp.sh/public-stun.txt)

Comment: +1 for the geekiest and actually most apropos technology. The http query works, which is what I've been using all my life, but I like that there's actually been some thought put into the question. I didn't know this. Thanks!

Comment: `stunclient stun.stunprotocol.org`

Comment: `brew install stuntman`

Comment: readymade for you. https://github.com/Jamesits/myip

Answer (score 13):

Type in this exactly, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> where indicated:

`telnet ipecho.net 80`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
`GET /plain HTTP/1.1`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
`HOST: ipecho.net` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
`BROWSER: web-kit`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This manually submits a HTTP request, which will return your IP at the bottom of a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK reply`

Example output:

```
$ telnet ipecho.net 80
Trying 146.255.36.1...
Connected to ipecho.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /plain HTTP/1.1
HOST: ipecho.net
BROWSER: web-kit

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2013 07:11:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

f
111.222.333.444
0
```

Comment: Nice, this worked well, not having to install curl was an advantage for me: one liner:  printf "GET /plain HTTP/1.1\nHOST: ipecho.net\nBROWSER: web-kit\n\n" | nc ipecho.net 80

Answer (score 11):

Another fast one (might well be the fastest, relatively)

```
curl ipecho.net/plain
```

Answer (score 9):

You can read a web page using only bash, without `curl`, `wget`:

```
$ exec 3<> /dev/tcp/icanhazip.com/80 && # open connection
  echo 'GET /' >&3 &&                   # send http 0.9 request
  read -u 3 && echo $REPLY &&           # read response
  exec 3>&-                             # close fd
```

Comment: This combined with `checkip.amazonaws.com` is the fastest for me

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan try a [dns request](https://askubuntu.com/a/427092/3712)

Comment: This answer is poetry to me. So elegant, and so cool to do it only using `bash`. Bravo and +1

Answer (score 8):

I have a stupid service for this by telnet. Something like this:

```
telnet myip.gelma.net

Your IPv4: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Your IPv6: ::ffff:xxxx:xxxx
```

Feel free to use it.

Comment: It prints: `Trying 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fe96:cc28...` and `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Unreachable here too -- it appears gelma.net may no longer be offering this service in 2022 (or may be using a different method now)

Answer (score 4):

## These will get the local IPs:

```
ifconfig
```

or for shorter output:

```
ifconfig | grep inet
```

also

```
ip addr show
```

and probably:

```
hostname -I
```

## This should get the external IP

```
wget http://smart-ip.net/myip -O - -q ; echo
```

---

*N.B.* If you don't mind to installing `curl`, this as well:

```
curl http://smart-ip.net/myip
```

Comment: `ifconfig | sed -nre '/^[^ ]+/{N;s/^([^ ]+).*addr: *([^ ]+).*/\1,\2/p}'` will print the local interfaces and corresponding V4 IP's

Comment: `ifconfig | sed -nre '/^[^ ]+/{N;N;s/^([^ ]+).*addr: *([^ ]+).*addr: *([^ ]+).*/\1,\2,\3/p}'` - v4 and v6 IPs.

Answer (score 3):

For those of us with login access to our routers, using a script to ask the router what its' WAN IP address is is the most efficient way to determine the external IP address. For instance the following python script prints out the external IP for my Medialink MWN-WAPR300N router:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
import re
from subprocess import check_output as co

cookie_jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

def get(url, values=None):
  data = None
  if values: data = urllib.urlencode(values)
  req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
  rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  return rsp.read()

router = co(['ip', '-o', 'ro', 'list', '0.0.0.0/0']).split()[2]
url = "http://" + router

get(url+"/index.asp")
get(url+"/LoginCheck", dict(checkEn='0', Username='admin', Password='admin'))
page = get(url+"/system_status.asp")

for line in page.split("\n"):
  if line.startswith("wanIP = "):
    print line.split('"')[1]
    exit(1)
```

Note that this is not very secure (as is the case with plaintext credentials & logging in to most routers), and is certainly not portable (needs to be changed for each router). It is however very fast and a perfectly reasonable solution on a physically secure home network.

To customize the script for another router, I recommend using the tamperdata addon in firefox to determine what HTTP requests to make.

Comment: You should try getting the IP address of the router grammatically. For example `router = subprocess.check_output(['ip', '-o', 'ro', 'list', '0.0.0.0/0']).split()[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

Many home routers can be queried by UPnP:

```
curl "http://fritz.box:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"" -H "SoapAction:urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#GetExternalIPAddress" -d "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <s:Envelope s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> <s:Body> <u:GetExternalIPAddress xmlns:u='urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1' /> </s:Body> </s:Envelope>" -s
```

Then, grep the ip address from the answer.

```
grep -Eo '\<[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}\>'
```

Comment: Tell me more, how do i see it on diferent routers?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **DD-WRT** then this works for me:

```
curl -s 192.168.1.1 | grep "ipinfo" | awk -v FS="(IP: |</span)" '{print $2}'
```

or

```
curl -s -u your_ddwrt_username:your_ddwrt_password http://192.168.1.1 | grep "ipinfo" | awk -v FS="(IP: |</span)" '{print $2}'
```

- Where 192.168.1.1 is the Gateway/Router LAN IP Address of the DD-WRT router.
- The **-s** component means silent (i.e. don't show the curl progress information).
- Oh, I should mention that I use the above with **"DD-WRT v24-sp2 (01/04/15) std"**.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed lynx in Ubuntu type

```
lynx bot.whatismyipaddress.com
```

Comment: `curl bot.whatismyipaddress.com` works too.

Answer (score 1):

use `ip`!

```
ip addr show
```

then look for the relevant adapter (not `lo`, and usually `eth0`), and locate the ip address near `inet`.

Comment: The question is about public not internal IP addresses

Comment: this works on our company servers -- if you do: ip addr show | grep inet (grep not absolutely required but better for output) you will get all ip addresses, local and external (including inet 6 protocol) - our servers are using CENTOS if your server does not somehow have the ip command. Similar output to: ifconfig | grep inet

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am a little late, but inxi can do it fairly easy.

Install `inxi`

```
sudo apt install inxi
```

Then run the following command

```
inxi -i
```

Example with my information blocked out using the `z` option for copy and paste to sites like this:

```
~$ inxi -iz
Network:   Card: NVIDIA MCP77 Ethernet driver: forcedeth
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           WAN IP: <filter>
           IF: eth0 ip-v4: <filter> ip-v6-link: N/A
```

*Where it says `<filter>` is where your WAN IP, IPv4, MAC address etc will appear*

Comment: Although not the fastest, it is the prettiest with color output.

Comment: inxi uses dig to the akamai whoami service. So is not pure local

Comment: @FrameGrace So, what's your point?  Most of these answers here are using external ways to get your Public IP.  If I really wanted to use 100% local my command with my OpenWRT router is `ssh root@10.0.0.1 'ip addr show pppoe-wan' | awk '/inet/ {print $2}'`, but my command won't work for everyone else here.

Answer (score -2):

Simply issue a traceroute for any website or service..

```
sudo traceroute -I google.com
```

Line 2 always seems to be my public IP address after it gets past my router gateway.

```
user@user-PC ~ $ sudo traceroute -I google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.46.104), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  25.0.8.1 (25.0.8.1)  230.739 ms  231.416 ms  237.819 ms
 2  199.21.149.1 (199.21.149.1)  249.136 ms  250.754 ms  253.994 ms**
```

So, make a bash command.

```
sudo traceroute -I google.com | awk -F '[ ]' '{ if ( $2 ="2" ) { print $5 } }'
```

And the output...

```
(199.21.149.1)
```

I don't think relying on PHP scripts and the sort is good practice.

Comment: this is interesting, though really slow and doesn't get my external ip like this

Comment: This answer is too inaccurate to be useful. In my corporate environment I don't get my IP address at all. The only way it works is if you understand how your local routers and switches are crafted, and even then it may not be on line 2 depending on the number of local hops you jump through. There's no way to make a coherent algorithm out of this technique, and there are many other solutions here that are simpler and will get you the proper answer every time.

Comment: While it may work in some special configurations, I have actually never seen my external IP in a traceroute. It is usually either my gateway (if I am not behind NAT), or my router's gateway, but mostly some other router further away.

Comment: alias ip='lynx --dump http://ipecho.net/plain'

Answer (score -2):

A command with no dependencies except 8.8.8.8 being a GOogle DNS:

```
echo $(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}')
```

Comment: This only tells you the IP-address of your local outgoing interface.

Comment: the command does show the public ip address if I run it on a cloud server. wasn;t that the question?

Comment: No, where do you see "cloud server"?

Comment: I am using a CENTOS server hosted by a remote company, and this works just fine on the command line.