# no-carrier | network interface didn't get any IP

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

My network interface didn't get an IP address. I get the error as follows:

```
3: eno2: NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:d9:8f:58:9c:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

4: enp179s0f0: NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:d9:8f:4e:d4:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`eno2` and `enp179s0f0` are plugged to switch and I assigned a static IP address.

I have 2 up interfaces and I didn't get any no-carrier error from them.

I tried this topics and they didnt work:

- [eth0 NO-CARRIER, ifconfig shows no IP address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497850/eth0-no-carrier-ifconfig-shows-no-ip-address)
- [Why is Netplan/Networkd not bringing up a static ethernet interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046420/why-is-netplan-networkd-not-bringing-up-a-static-ethernet-interface)

Comment: Are you positive that there's actuallly an cable plugged into those two NIC's?

Comment: yes i am sure. i changed interface eno2 to enp179s0f0. Now i plugged to enp179s0f0.

Comment: I solved the issue. We wrote a bash script for add routing. In this script we down-up interface for ssh bind interface so that it convert no carrier to interface.

Comment: @Kadir Y. If you solved it, could you add an answer with the details about the solution (and then remove the SOLVED in the title)?

Comment: @LorenzKeel i wrote the answer above. Again, when you change the interface up-down status rapidly, interface comes to no-carrier.

Comment: @KadirY. Hey, could you please elaborate a bit because I have the same problem and dont really understand the answer you gave. Would you mind sharing the bash script?

Comment: Hi @randomperson Main cause is interface situation is changing rapidly. I mean if you up or down your network interface you get NO-CARRIER error. Do not change routing or interface state rapidly.