# How to use the terminal to change the IP address provided by Tor?

Tags: command-line, services, ip, tor

I have the [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) service, and I want to use the terminal to change the IP address which Tor gives me.  In other words: How do I request a new IP address from Tor on the command line?

Comment: an even better way to say it is how to "change identity" from a terminal

Comment: I added another command that I found for when running the tor daemon on Ubuntu in the background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-tor-exit-node-programmatically

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For tor daemon running on Ubuntu, first try this:

```
killall -HUP tor
```

If that does not work, enable the control port in your torrc file.

Then, set a password for the control port with `tor --hash-password password`

Open a telnet connection to the control port and issue the NEWNYM command:

```sh
printf 'AUTHENTICATE "password"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
```

sources:

- [SuperUser: How do I tell tor, from the command-line, to give me a new identity in a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/330064/how-do-i-tell-tor-from-the-command-line-to-give-me-a-new-identity)
- [Stack Overflow: How to request new TOR identity in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987518/how-to-request-new-tor-identity-in-terminal)
- [SuperUser: How to “flush tor circuit”](https://superuser.com/questions/138262/how-to-flush-tor-circuit)

Comment: For the newbs out there,  you must first set the hashed password on your torrc like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/989108/52975

Answer (score 24):

You can simply type or insert in your bash script:

```
service tor reload
```

Comment: I needed `sudo`, but this worked.

Comment: To me this is actually a better answer then the one @mchid gave. The reload command will trigger the running tor executable to reload its configuration and setup a new circuit (and thus get new IP). The other answer will kill the running executable and restart it. This might take longer and cause other services depening on tor's proxy to be there to fail.

Comment: I don't know why others suggested such a complicated solution while this simple line can solve the problem

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha Because this doesn't work for multiple tor instances

Comment: @Alex If you just use the second method and issue the NEWNYM command, it will stay running and you will get a new IP because it will switch to clean circuits.

Answer (score 9):

**Method 1: HUP**

Mentioned at [Change IP address which is given by Tor using the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499995/change-ip-address-which-is-given-by-tor-using-the-terminal/500002#500002) but here go a few more details:

```
sudo killall -HUP tor
```

Then check that your IP has changed with:

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
```

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10 with `sudo apt-get install tor` version 1.6.0-5.

`sudo` is needed since the process is started by root by default.

What an HUP signal does exactly to the Tor daemon is documented at: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=03aaace9bd9459b0d4bf22a75012acf39d07bcec#n394 and is equivalent to sending some command through the command port.

Browser Bundle 5.0.5 is not affected by this, only daemon ports like the default 9050, which is not used by the TBB. For that use case see: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1071/how-can-a-new-circuit-happen-without-closing-all-tabs

If you are deploying an army of Tor IPs [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18895491/895245) you can selectively send:

```
kill -HUP $PID
```

**Method 2: control port**

Mentioned by [kat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354585/895245):

```
(echo authenticate '""'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc localhost 9051
```

but for that to work on Ubuntu 17.10 you **must first**:

- enable the control port by uncommenting:

  ```
  ControlPort 9051
  ```

  from `/etc/tor/torrc`
- Set the empty password, otherwise it gives `515 Authentication failed: Wrong length on authentication cookie.`. First run:

  ```
  tor --hash-password ''
  ```

  This outputs something like:

  ```
  16:D14CC89AD7848B8C60093105E8284A2D3AB2CF3C20D95FECA0848CFAD2
  ```

  Now on `/etc/tor/torrc` update the line:

  ```
  HashedControlPassword 16:D14CC89AD7848B8C60093105E8284A2D3AB2CF3C20D95FECA0848CFAD2
  ```
- Restart Tor:

  ```
  sudo service tor restart
  ```

**Bonus: how to check that your IP changed**

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
```

See also:

- https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/100/can-tor-be-used-with-applications-other-than-web-browsers
- [Command for determining my public IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip)

**Related threads**

- https://superuser.com/questions/449060/tor-how-to-have-different-ip-address-for-every-page-request
- [Change IP address which is given by Tor using the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499995/change-ip-address-which-is-given-by-tor-using-the-terminal)
- https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/100/can-tor-be-used-with-applications-other-than-web-browsers
- [Command for determining my public IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip)

Comment: Such complicated solutions for such a simple function (`get new circuit`). I don't trust tor at all anymore. I think it is full of bugs and glitches to make us expose ourselves

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a control port and use the python script

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Comment: Do you know how to wait until the new ip is set?

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner that makes tor use a different ip address:

```
systemctl show -p MainPID tor | cut -d= -f2 | xargs sudo kill -HUP
```