# Proxychain with static IP untill tor reload

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, static-ip

I recently installed tor privoxy and proxychains on my 14.04lts works ok as intended. There is no acctualy problem with functioning, I have problem with setup. As I always used it with config dynamic_chain (so only 1 server should be online to play in chain) and it does. Anyway this option changes IP every idk lets say 5 or 10 minutes. I am wondering is there way to make it not changing ip address, like give it list of ip addresses to switch between and give it limit of 1 ip per session? To make it simple, you start tor privoxy and proxychains, it picks ip from list you suply and does not change that ip picked untill you say ok now change it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the option `MaxCircuitDirtiness` set it for number of seconds. By default it is set to 10 minutes (600). One hour is 3600, 4 hours would be 14400, and so on.

Add this option in your torrc file. There is usually a max to the number so if you are manually editing torrc with nano or vim, you may need to play with  the number if your initial ideal setting is too large.

Otherwise just edit the torrc file through the tor control panel and you should be notified of any syntax error or whatever.

To toggle a new IP, see my answer here:

[Change IP address which is given by Tor using the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/500002/167115)

Sources:

[www.torproject.org](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#MaxCircuitDirtiness)

[How to prevent TOR Vidalia from changing my IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18578120/3393576)

---

As for the list of IPs, I am assuming you are referring to a list of exit nodes. You can limit the exit nodes using the `ExitNodes` option in your torrc file.

[www.torproject.org](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExitNodes)

Comment: Man this is great answer but not in range of what I am looking for. To be perfectly clear, I want to have full control of what IP address would be picked and at what time. So that is why I look at way to supply list with strict IP addresses and in specific order to pick it, no after new time I will set in torrc, but in time I decide, now i need that IP lets switch to it. Did my question makes sense now?

Comment: @black_hat_cat this looks promising https://stem.torproject.org/ and it uses Tor's control protocol referenced here https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt