# Terminal command on how to close an app gracefully and restart it back once per day at a given time

Tags: command-line

As the title says, I'd like to schedule basically a graceful termination of an app and then have it restarted after the termination. The reason for this is that the app seldomly hangs with no exact pattern. Restarting it once a day would fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: What application is this? Depending on the application, you may be able to send a [hang up signal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103610/what-does-hup-do-when-used-with-killall) to the app to cause it to kind of restart. Here is [another example](https://askubuntu.com/a/500002/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal to gracefully terminate an application is `SIGTERM` (signal number 15) - and a forceful kill is `SIGKILL` (signal number 9).

Alternatively, for some applications you could use `SIGHUP` (signal number 1), to restart the application and reload the config.

So the basic command would look like:

```
kill -s 15 -p <PID>
```

One way to find the `PID` of the process is to use `pgrep` - or you could use the combined command `pkill`, which finds using `pgrep` and then sends a signal (`SIGTERM` by default).

If you were to kill `htop` (doesn't really make sense, but just as an example) and start it again, the script commands would be: (run as root)

```
# pkill sends signal 15 as default
pkill htop
# start htop again
htop
```

Or in case a `SIGHUP` is enough:

```
# tell pkill to send signal 1 instead
pkill -s 1 htop
```

Even another option would be to use the `killall` command, which also sends signals by process name.

Also see man pages:

- [`kill`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/kill.1.html)
- [`pgrep`/`pkill`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/pkill.1.html)
- [`killall`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/killall.1.html)

And finally see [additional info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690415/in-what-order-should-i-send-signals-to-gracefully-shutdown-processes).