# access the server with the standard ip address

Tags: server, ssh, ip

Actually, the only way I could access my AWS server is with the IPv4 DNS hostname:

```
ssh -i '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' something.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I would like to access it with the IPv4 Public IP, but I did not succeed in doing that so far. I tried using the simple command `ssh my_ip`, but nothing happened.

What do I have to modify on the configuration so that I can use the IP address to access the server.

Comment: Have you assigned an EIP to your VM?

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you're using ssh to the IP, you're not using the key. Try

```
ssh -i "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" server_ip
```

Also, make sure you're using the external IP of the server

```
curl ipinfo.io/ip
```

(check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip))